# Having issues with setting an even listener to prevent default in input field with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to make a simple password generator and i want the password generation to happen on the click of a button and that part works when i test it in the console. And now to implement it on sort of a real web page, the password generated  to the input field doesn't stay!!, i know to use the `.preventDefault()` method but  i don't know hot to apply it in this case using an event listener for when the value of the input field changes.
I couldn't add the html because it looks strange when i add it, but it looks like this:

```
Password: <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="">
<button id="button" onclick="makePassword()">Get password</button>
```

here is my code below:

```
var capitalAlphabets=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
    var smallAlphabets=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
    var numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,];
    function randomCapital(){
        var capital=capitalAlphabets[Math.floor(Math.random()*capitalAlphabets.length)];
        return capital;
    }
    function randomSmall(){
        var small=smallAlphabets[Math.floor(Math.random()*smallAlphabets.length)];
        return small;
    }
    function randomNumber(){
        var number=numbers[Math.floor(Math.random()*numbers.length)];
        return number;

    }
    var password="";
    function makePassword(){
        password="";
        for(var i=0; i<=12; i++){
            password=password+randomCapital()+randomSmall()+randomNumber(); 
            // console.log(i + password);
        }
        console.log(password);
        input=document.getElementById("password");
        input.value=password;
    }
    //having issues with setting an even listener to prevent default in input field
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have your `button` inside a `form` so it is interpreted as a submit button (`<button type="submit">`). Pressing enter inside an `input` field inside a `form` will click on the first submit button inside the form. Just explicity make the button type a button so clicking it will not submit the form and refresh the page:

```
<button type="button" onclick="makePassword()">Get password</button>
```

If you want to add an event listener, use `document.getElementById` to get the DOM element to add a keypress event listener to and if the event's keycode is 13 (enter), prevent the default action.

```
document.getElementById("password").addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
  if(e.keyCode==13){
   e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: @Edmund No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, using `onclick=""` for a button is bad practice.

You should add an eventListener for your button instead:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  makePassword();
});
```

That should work much better, let me know if you have any questions.

http://jsfiddle.net/316xjkqu/2/